# CSS nesting rules not working on jupyterlab. how to fix?

Tags: css, sass, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

the problem is modern native CSS supports nesting rules in browsers. But it doesn't work on jupyterlab or jupyter notebooks and I dont know why. Nested css is included in bundled code, still not working tho. What can be the issue and how can I fix it?

(I want to use native CSS rather than SASS, so please do not suggest "use SASS instead". I would rather love to solve the issue)

i've tried nesting rules on jupyterlab local dev, jupyterlab online, jupyter notebook online, jupyterlite online. None worked :((

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you look in the Jupyter Discouse forum for advice? There's dicussions I recall about using CSS with JupyterLab , and Jupyter Notebook 7+, because they require different approaches than older Jupyter Notebook (Version 6.4 and earlier and NbClassic) to play nicely with it.

Comment: I think [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/a-way-to-access-the-predefined-style-values-via-python/17435/4?u=fomightez) was some of what I was thinking of about CSS playing nicely.

Comment: That one has nothing to do actually with my question, sir. But thank you anyways for sharing

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping something about playing nicely with JupyterLab's code in regards to CSS would spark some idea of what was going on with your issue.

Comment: Anyone interested in more information on the OP topic, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/css-nesting-rules-not-working-on-jupyterlab-how-to-fix/22247/2?u=fomightez) and links therein.